# Copying or redirecting text as input to UART, need to enforce slower bandwidth

Tags: io-redirection, gnu-screen, uart

Basically i'm completely sick of typing lots & lots of text. Obviously want type it in file, push it to UART U-Boot, then modify file, try again.

But neither Shift+Ctrl+C over `screen ttyUSB0 115200` works correctly, or `cat file.cmd > ttyUSB0`.

Anyone had fancy ways of copying to UART? I can't be the only one who tried to do something like this.

Comment: Look at `man stty` to see if you have to change the settings of the port; `stty -a /dev/ttyUSB0` will show the current settings, And make sure you are in the correct group (usually `dialout`, see `ls -l /dev/ttyUSB*`and `id`). With the correct settings `cat file > /dev/ttyUSB0` or `cp file /dev/ttyUSB0`should work.

Comment: Haha, no. I said my problem is that redirection is too fast, where input turns into gibberish.

Comment: Also have a look at `pv -L` if you want something more featureful than your `slowpipe` script.

Comment: `screen` has a `slowpaste` command that may help. For more sophisticated automatic serial line conversations there is `expect` which has a `send -s` slow send command, or the venerable `ckermit` which is scriptable but with a higher learning curve. (The python `pexpect` version of expect does not have a slow send.)

Answer (score 1):

Well, had to make a lil' script to do this, eh, good enough:

```
cat > slowpipe << 'EOF'    
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -eu

data=$(< /dev/stdin)
hz=$(bc -l <<< "1.0 / $1")
while [ -n "$data" ]; do
    printf '%s' "${data:0:1}"
    data=${data:1}
    sleep $hz
done

# XXX It seems to be imposible to save leading newlines in variables,
# you cant have var=$'\n'$'\n' no mater what you do, only one new line can will
# be saved, IFS won't help, or anything. one way is to use `read`, without
# saving all stdin to variable.
echo
EOF

chmod 755 slowpipe
./slowpipe 42 < rpi.cmd >> /dev/ttyUSB0
```